# "Current render engine does not support baking" when calling bpy.ops.object.bake(type='SHADOW')?

Tags: python, texture-baking

I'm trying to write a script that creates a texture of the shadows on an object. It's supposed to create a new image texture, set the selected object to edit mode, perform a UV smart project, then bake the shadows using " bpy.ops.object.bake(type='SHADOW') "

However, when blender gets to this line, it gives the error " Current render engine does not support baking ". Even though if I omit this line, and click the bake button under the Render properties menu, it works fine.

Also, calling the line " print(bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.engine) " just prior to the bake function call prints "BLENDER RENDER", which to me implies that the expected engine is in fact selected.

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: A quick look shows that the operator you might need is `bpy.ops.object.bake_image`. Have a look if it's giving you the same trouble.

Comment: That is helpful, but now I have another issue with setting the destination image, receiving an error message "No valid images found to bake to." Any help with this one?

Comment: I am encountering the exact same problem of no valid images found. Were u able to solve it?