# Blender bake error 'Current render engine does not support baking' when calling bpy.ops.object.bake(type = 'DIFFUSE')

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, texture-baking

I am currently attempting to bake diffuse image textures using python in blender. I know this question is extremely similar to ["Current render engine does not support baking" when calling bpy.ops.object.bake(type='SHADOW')?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53829/current-render-engine-does-not-support-baking-when-calling-bpy-ops-object-bake) but the question is unanswered and the comment that has a possible solution gives me a different error.

My code currently manipulates the node editor in a way such that everything is set up for baking. Note that the lines at the bottom connect to an image texture that I decided to omit because it makes my ss too blurry.
[image]

I am now trying to bake these materials but when I run the following segment of code it gives me an error.
[image]

[image]

When I change the call from bpy.ops.object.bake_image() however it give me a typing error.

[image]
[image]

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't share screenshots of your code, share the code.

Comment: My bad dude, I will in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch to `Cycles` render engine and use [`bpy.ops.object.bake()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.object.html#bpy.ops.object.bake).

`bpy.ops.object.bake_image()` is used to bake `Normal` and `Displacement` from multires modifier.